# Move the Search Box in Magento into Main Page

Tags: magento, search, magento-1.7

I am trying to move the search box into my main page. Specifically, at the start of my ‘col-main’ section (main section). I have Googled the problem and have been trying for hours, and am really struggling..

I copied this from my ‘default/modern/layout/catalogsearch.xml’ page:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.bar">
        <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

and pasted it into my ‘default/modern/layout/page.xml’ page, under ‘Page Header’ and before ‘Left Column’.

I then went into ‘default/modern/template/page/3columns.phtml’ and pasted this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(‘topSearch’) ?>
```

within this section:

```
<div class="col-main">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml(‘topSearch’) ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
```

And I get nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you remove the reference top.bar, is it working?

Comment: So sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately that makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create or update your local.xml file

You need to add the block to the correct section.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Then call it using the way that you currently are using.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(‘topSearch’) ?>
```

The only problem with what you did is that you were referencing top.bar for the location. when you reference it the way I presented you now have access to the search on any page on the site.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I cannot find a 'local.xml' file anywhere, so I created one and placed it in 'default/modern/layout/' with exactly what you had pasted above, but unfortunately that still didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I forgot I made a much longer more detailed explanation of this prior. Make sure that you check your file path.  Because if something is being overridden none of these changes are going to show up. Go to this link and check out my answer here. I made step by step instructional post. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181827/how-to-move-my-magento-mini-search-form-to-another-spot-in-my-template-header/21419346#21419346)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by just adjusting my CSS. Probably not the most ideal way, but it seemed to work at least.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it.. whenever you have time.. ?

Comment: I take it back. I did it by adding this to my css:
     .top-bar {
 line-height:21px;
 float: right;
 width: 680px;
 padding-top: 61px;
 padding-right: 12px;
 padding-left: 12px;
 margin-bottom: -61px;
     }

but now I can't click on any of the links :(

Answer (score 0):

You should move the block to content;

Unset child block from `top.bar`:

```
<reference name="top.bar">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>top.search</name></action>
<reference>
```

Add to `content`:

```
<reference name="content">
    <action method="insert"><name>top.search</name></action>
</reference>
```